# Is there a anything in react native that responds to a mouse hover over event?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Using the latest react-native library.

Is there a way to respond to a mouse hovering over a component in react native?

I can't find any components in the library that use this capability

Comment: Hi, whats your use case here, what do you want to achieve by doing that

Comment: I'm using the new pressable component with react-native-web, and I wanted to change the underlying colour when I hovered over the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using react-native-web ? mouse hover events happen on the web.

*EDIT: as @user56reinstatemonica8 said hover events can also happen on Android/iOS*

if so you can use this `useHover` hook from [react-native-web-hooks](https://github.com/EvanBacon/react-native-web-hooks#create-pseudo-class-styles) to respond to mouse hover events.

Otherwise you can use [Touchables](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches#touchables) in react-native to handle touch events.

Comment: "hover events happen only on the web" - absolutely not true. Android has [View.OnHoverListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnHoverListener) which is triggered by "air hover" from pens like the Samsung S-pen or mouse hover if a phone or tablet is connected to a mouse. iOS has [UIHoverGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uihovergesturerecognizer) which is similar.